# clj-record: when is :before-save called?

Tags: random, clojure, lazy-evaluation

I'm using `rand` to assign a field value as a `:before-save` function in *clj-record*. The `random-str` function below is used to generate the value.

```
(def VALID-CHARS
    (map char (concat (range 48 58) ; 0-9
        (range 65 91) ; A-Z
        (range 97 123)))) ; a-z

(defn random-char []
    (nth VALID-CHARS (rand (count VALID-CHARS))))

(defn random-str [length]
    (apply str (take length (repeatedly random-char))))
```

When I subsequently use the map returned from the *clj-record* `create` functon, the value of that field is different to what's in the database. Does this mean there's some lazy evaluation wierdness going on? Is `random-str` being called more than once?

Comment: psst. (defn random-char [] (rand-nth VALID-CHARS))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like an issue with clj-record.

You get laziness in clojure only with lazy sequences, or with [delays](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/delay).
Otherwise, clojure is a strictly/eagerly evaluated language.

Comment: That was my suspicion. I can't see why rand would be evaluated more than once unless there are atoms or refs in use inside clj-record. Functions involved in transactions shouldn't have side effects and rand has state, so I guess I'll put it down to experience.